# Wordpress Author Query

Tags: wordpress, author

I've changed my approach and edited the get_related_author fucntion, but its only bringing in 1 post can someone see where I'm going wrong?

```
function get_related_author_posts() {
global $authordata, $post;
$authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID, 
'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
$output = '<div class="listio"><ul><li> <div class="author-post">';
$output .= '<div style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) !important;  
width: 80px; height: 50px; float: left; margin-right: 13px; 
background-size: 80px 50px!important; background-color: pink;"></div>';
$output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '">' . 
apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) .  
'</a>';
$output .= '</div></li></ul></div>';
}


return $output;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to get author's ID from outside the loop. Then create $wpdb query to get all posts by author.

Comment: Any ideas? anyone on this?

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
function get_author_related_posts($author_id, $excluded_post){

    global $wpdb;
    $author_posts = $wpdb->get_results(
        "
    SELECT post_author, ID
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_author = '$author_id' and ID != '$excluded_post'
    ORDER BY ID DESC
    "
    );

    return $author_posts;
}
```